# how to read nested mongoDB atrributes in llama-index

Tags: langchain, llama-index

am trying to access and read document from mongoDB,

```
query_dict = {

    "details.description": {"$exists": True}
}
field_names = ["details.description"]

reader = SimpleMongoReader(connection_string, 27017)
documents = reader.load_data(
        db_name, collection_name, field_names, query_dict)
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
index.storage_context.persist()
```

the library seems to only read first level keys, my target is `details.description` but when I run the code I get `ValueError:` details.description `field not found in Mongo document.`, I've checked the implemented library and does seem to only expect first level and won't read nested, is there a solution for that other than changing the llama-index implementation ?